# DBVisualizer Hive SSH Tunnel Ignoring Server Information

Tags: hadoop, hive, ssh-tunnel, dbvisualizer

I'm attempting to setup a connection to our Hadoop cluster via DBVisualizer.

In order to connect I need to SSH into a server on the domain and then I need to run the command to a remote server (I've not ssh'd onto the Hadoop cluster directly)

I have (figuratively)

```
Database Server: abcd.efg
Database Port: 12345
Database: Hello
```

configured for the Database section

```
SSH Host: hijk.efg
SSH Port: 678
```

When I attempt a connection, it returns

> Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
>   jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:-----
>   Where `127.0.0.1` and `-----` appear to be the defaults instead of what I entered.

Any idea how I get the SSH tunnel to use the server configuration I specify?

Answer (score 0):

The SSH Tunnel is set up locally on the client, so connecting to the port on localhost tunnels you to the SSH Host/Port, which then sets up a connection to the database server/port you have specified. This page may help:

http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Using+an+SSH+Tunnel

Best Regards,
Hans